# Discord.js changing perms

Tags: discord, discord.js

Let say I want to make a lock command (making only admins be able to say something in a channel) and I want a specific role to be overwrite (not @everyone). How could I do that?

To simply it. How can I disable SEND_MESSAGE for a specific role? /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to achieve this via  `GuildChannel.permissionOverwrites` which returns the `PermissionOverwriteManager` class. Within that class, you will be able to use the [`.edit()` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/PermissionOverwriteManager?scrollTo=edit) which

> *Edits permission overwrites for a user or role in this channel, or creates an entry if not already present*.

In the first parameter of the `.edit()` method, you can input the role ID as a string, and in the options, you can input the property, or as known as the permission, with a value of `true` to enable or value `false` to disable.

The documentation for the `PermissionOverwriteManager.edit()` method includes this example:

> ```js
> // Edit or Create permission overwrites for a message author
> message.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.author, {
>   SEND_MESSAGES: false
> })
>   .then(channel => console.log(channel.permissionOverwrites.cache.get(message.author.id)))
>   .catch(console.error);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GuildChannel.permissionOverwrites.edit` to set permission overwrite.

The code would be:

```js
message.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit('replace with role id', {
  SEND_MESSAGE: false
})
```

Slash command version:

```js
interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit('replace with role id', {
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
})
```